# Error 404 requested resource is not available with tomcat in netbeans

Tags: java, tomcat, resources, netbeans-8

Whenever I try to run a **.jsp** with TomCat I get this error:

[image: 404 error]

But it's only with **.jsp** files. With **.html** files there are no problems. I have tried with Netbeans 13 and 8.2, and with TomCat and GlassFish, and always get the same error.

This is the structure of the project:

[image: Project structure]

This is the **jsp** content:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

The xml content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/WebApplication1"/>
```

And the server log

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "G:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331"
Using CLASSPATH:       "G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\bin\bootstrap.jar;G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Using CATALINA_OPTS:   ""
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.386 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Nombre de la versiÃ³n del servidor: Apache Tomcat/8.5.81
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.401 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:                      Jun 8 2022 21:30:15 UTC
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.401 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log NÃºmero de versiÃ³n de servidor:     8.5.81.0
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.401 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:                           Windows 10
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log VersiÃ³n de Systema Operativo:      10.0
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Arquitectura:                      amd64
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:                         G:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_331\jre
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:                       1.8.0_331-b09
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Vededor JVM:                       Oracle Corporation
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:                     G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:                     G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Djava.util.logging.config.file=G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\logging.properties
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=localhost|127.0.0.1|SALOMON-PC
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.402 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Dcatalina.base=G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.403 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Dcatalina.home=G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.403 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument:             -Djava.io.tmpdir=G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\temp
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.403 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Cargada la biblioteca nativa APR de Apache Tomcat [1.2.33] con la versiÃ³n APR [1.7.0].
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.403 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Capacidades APR: IPv6 [true], enviar fichero [true], aceptar filtros [false], aleatorio [true], UDS [{4}].
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.403 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.491 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL inicializado correctamente [OpenSSL 1.1.1o  3 May 2022]
14-Jun-2022 22:45:59.993 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Inicializando el manejador de protocolo ["http-nio-8080"]

14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.016 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 959 ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.093 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Arrancando servicio [Catalina]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.093 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/8.5.81]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.099 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\ff.xml]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.140 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7acb0d5d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5018)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [G:\PruebaJSP\ff\build\web] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 13 more
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.140 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error durante el despliegue del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\ff.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7acb0d5d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5018)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [G:\PruebaJSP\ff\build\web] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 13 more
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.143 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\ff.xml] has finished in [42] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.182 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\PruebaJSP.xml]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.186 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
    org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2ca1bc3d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5018)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [G:\PruebaJSP\PruebaJSP\build\web] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 13 more
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.187 GRAVE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Error durante el despliegue del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\PruebaJSP.xml]
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:757)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:673)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
    Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@2ca1bc3d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4880)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5018)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:753)
        ... 9 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [G:\PruebaJSP\PruebaJSP\build\web] is not valid
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:748)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        ... 13 more
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.260 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\PruebaJSP.xml] has finished in [78] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.261 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Desplieque del descriptor de configuraciÃ³n [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication1.xml]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.620 ADVERTENCIA [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [182] milliseconds.
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.632 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\conf\Catalina\localhost\WebApplication1.xml] has finished in [371] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.632 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el directorio [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\docs] de la aplicaciÃ³n web
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.651 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\docs] has finished in [19] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:00.651 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el directorio [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\examples] de la aplicaciÃ³n web
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.012 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\examples] has finished in [361] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.013 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el directorio [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\host-manager] de la aplicaciÃ³n web
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.055 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\host-manager] has finished in [42] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.055 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Desplegando el directorio [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\manager] de la aplicaciÃ³n web
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.074 INFORMACIÃ“N [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [G:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.81-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-8.5.81\webapps\manager] has finished in [19] ms
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.076 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
14-Jun-2022 22:46:01.088 INFORMACIÃ“N [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 1071 ms
```

**SOLUTION (at least in my case): Change the Index name of the .jsp to index (all in lowercase)**

Comment: The underlying issue appears to be the `IllegalArgumentException` errors in the stack traces in the logs, with the message The _"main resource set specified [G:\PruebaJSP\ff\build\web] is not valid"_. But that is a generic message, and there are several questions on SO similar to yours, with multiple underlying causes/solutions. Try searching on SO for _"main resource set specified" "is not valid"_ and review the answers. If you are still stuck then update your question with what you attempted that did not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot of solutions, it was really easy. Apparently the problem was in the capital I of Index, the moment i changed the .jsp name to index, all in lowercases, the file run whithout problems.